# Microbit V1 servo motor's problem, it always does the entire return

Tags: micropython, bbc-microbit

the thing is that i'm working with Python in Micro Python for Microbit Editor.
I'm trying to set the angle of a servomotor, but the thing is that it is giving the entire return.

```
pin0.set_analog_period(20)

while True:
    pin0.write_analog(50)
    sleep(3000)
    pin0.write_analog(75)
```

The same thing is happening when I try to code it with blocks

Comment: Have you tried the debugging ideas at: https://support.microbit.org/support/solutions/articles/19000101864-using-a-servo-with-the-micro-bit#troubleshooting

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *it is giving the entire return* please? One obvious issue with your code is that there is no delay between writing the value 75 and writing the value 50 in the next loop iteration, so effectively it will be as if you just executed `pin0.write_analog(50)` with no loop.